# How to find out what touchpad I have under Linux?

Tags: linux, touchpad

I tried `lspci`, `lsusb` and `lshw` but none of those lists my touchpad device. Where to look now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lshal -u "$(hal-find-by-capability --capability input.touchpad)"
```

Comment: This command no longer works under Debian

Comment: hal is long deprecated on many distros. This answer is out of date.

Comment: @EricS so what's the updated answer?